# Deriving TVOC value in ppb/ppm units

Tags: gas-sensor

Our project requires a Total VOC value in ppb or ppm units. But the sensors on the market give relative resistance change. How can I derive the TVOC ppb/ppm value?  Or I don't know if there is such a sensor on the market?

- No need for specific gas detection or ppb/ppm value for it.
  Example VOC sensor: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3199/MiCS-5524.pdf
  NOTE: The challenge can be here that since I do not know the exact gas in the environment, I cannot convert the resistance to ppm by solving the linear equation.

SENSOR CHARACTERISTICS
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOX gas sensors don't measure TVOC directly; but the digital sensors which do on-board processing can give you an estimate based on whatever proprietary algorithms they've developed. Have a look at these:

- BME680 / BME688
- ENS160
- SGP30
- CCS811

That list will become outdated, but in general all digital gas sensors give you some sort of TVOC estimate because air conditioning is one of the main applications.

The estimate may not be super accurate though, especially outside of a typical office/residential environment.

To do the same thing with an analog-output gas sensor, you would need to develop your own model that maps sensor resistance to TVOC.
This is not trivial. First you need to compensate for a lot of things:

- temperature
- humidity
- drift (sensor responses to a given air mixture are not necessarily stable over time, and depend on the age of the sensor as well as previous exposures)

Then you need to translate the sensor signal to a measure of TVOC. If you don't know which gases are present in the environment, this is indeed impossible, unfortunately.

What the digital sensors do is make an educated guess about the gasses the sensor is likely to encounter in its target application. Typically, the manufacturer would collect some ground truth data in a controlled environment (precisely-controlled air mixtures, spectrometers, etc.), train a machine learning model to predict the true TVOC from the sensor resistance, and store that model in the sensor firmware. The prediction may or may not be good enough in your particular case -- you would have to make some tests to find out.

In general, though, sensors that combine multiple gas sensor types with different sensitivity curves (eg. ENS160) will give you a more accurate estimate, because they can to some extend disambiguate the mix of gasses in the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've used SGP30 in a project one year ago, but now outdated as you said. I thought that they've made some mistakes so they release SGP40 which does not give output in ppb.  (Just an estimation from me). But it doesn't give ppb/ppm. I checked also BME680, it only gives breathe VOC as ppm, not TVOC. I'm stuck since I don't know which gas is present exactly in the environment, so I can't estimate TVOC from the sensor output. Each gas response are different from another.

Comment: @berker you are correct, it is impossible to compute an exact TVOC from these gas sensors, precisely for the reason you mention. It is only ever going to be an approximation; whether it's good enough depends on your application. A bit more on this on page 21 of this document: https://www.sciosense.com/wp-content/uploads/documents/ENS160-White-Paper.pdf

Comment: Please can you correct me ENS160 is able to give TVOC[ppb], am I right? I've edited my question adding repsonse curves, how the sensor estimates ppm while 10 ppb X Gas creates 1kohm and 100ppb Y Gas creates also 1kohm resistance. How does it understand and say rough ppb value?

Comment: Up to %20 estimation errors can be tolerable in our application. But looking at sensor curves, I really wonder how they can infer ppb? Curves for the different gases are very away and very different. They should make big estimation mistakes or should be a tricky way.

Comment: @berker I've added some more info. You are correct, it is tricky and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

**You're looking at a serious investment in terms of effort, equipment and supplies, and time. This isn't a weekend project**.

Assuming that you want to use raw sensor signals, you'll have to:

1. Obtain reference gases, and a mixing manifold with flow meters so that you can mix them at the desired ratios. And obviously a lab setting where there's ample exhaust, excess gas monitoring, etc.
2. Have a means of generating reference humid air, since the sensor performance has to be characterized at a range of humidities.
3. Have a vacuum system and a pressure regulator to sweep the range of atmospheric pressures you'd specify your device for. You'd be basically pulling slight vacuum from the sensor test cavity, to lower the gas pressure. Gas mix comes in via an orifice.
4. Have a calibrated reference gas analyzer so that you can validate the performance of your calibration/characterization setup, and maintain metrological reference to relevant metrological standards.
5. Characterize the sensor you're using the reference gases, at various temperatures, humidities, and pressures, and with relation to aging.
6. Develop signal processing needed to condition the signals using the discoveries from preceding step, and implement them in your product.

That's why professionally made gas mixture sensors are in a different price group than the raw sensors they use. They take a bit of effort to make, calibrate, and ensure quality control. And the potential liability is also higher than in less critical applications.

For production line calibration and testing, you'll need to have the setup described above completely automated - not that big of a deal these days, since the components needed to put it together are readily available, but some bits are pricy. Also, learning how to do all this is fun and all, and a greatly satisfying challenge IMHO, but practical constraints of time-to-market and cost may indicate getting a consultant to help out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure for now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What do you think about the ENS160? https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/1081/SC_001224_DS_1_ENS160_Datasheet_Rev_0_95-2258311.pdf

Comment: Don't I read about it, right? It's able to give TVOC in ppb unit?

Comment: @berker ENS160 does it, yes. It has an on-board CPU to do the math, and they did all the hard work I described above already. So it's an extremely good value for money, if you can buy it that is :)